# Convert a string from a custom base to another

Tags: java, php, decode, encode

How do I convert a string (the string has numbers and alphabets) from a base (ranges from 1 to 64) to another base (ranges from 1 to 64).

Now, I googled and found out a solution which does it.

```
String converted = Integer.toString(Integer.parseInt(input, radix1),radix2);
```

In the above line of code, the input is converted from radix1 to radix2 however, if the input is a string is for example:- "ZZZZ" and radix1 is 30 and I try to convert it to base 10, then I get an Exception.

The characters allowed are "23456789ABCDEFGHJKMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ". Here 0, 1, I, and L are ommitted.

Comment: You need radix 36 to parse `"ZZZZ"` (10 digits + 26 letters).